# Docker failed to initialize | Docker Desktop is shutting down

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am facing an issue with Docker for Windows application. This is happening after updating to newer version of 4.3.2. Previous version was running without any issues. After downloading and updating to new version, whenever I launch Docker Desktop I get error message " Docker failed to initialize. Docker Desktop is shutting down. ".

I have tried many solutions like:

1. Closed docker and restarted laptop after update.
2. Deleting log files in `C:\Users\{...}\AppData\Local\Docker`
3. Deleting files in `C:\Users\{...}\AppData\Roaming\Docker`
4. Tried to bump to previous release but unsuccessful with the message
   [image: Docker]
   [image: Docker launch]

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue as I have already wasted few hours to resolve this.

I am not sure if I should completely uninstall docker and install freshly. If doing so, may **remove all existing volumes and containers.** I don't want to lose existing containers and data. BTW, I didn't sign-in while working with containers.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P.S: I am working with Docker for Windows on Windows 10 machine with WSL2 enabled. I have also enabled Containers and Virtual Machine Platform in Windows Features.

Comment: Checking the log file for additional info is always useful: `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed Docker Desktop 4.3.2 for Windows. But before installing I took the backup of `ext4.vhdx` file present in `C:\Users\{...}\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data`. But fortunately any of the volumes and containers were removed and everything is restored and working fine.

To be on safer side, if anyone is facing similar situation please have the backup of `ext4.vhdx` and you can restore your data from it.

Answer (score 36):

It worked for me after removing the **settings.json** file as shown below

[image]

Comment: If only the Docker Desktop dev team had read this answer earlier, the update I installed today (3 Nov 2022) wouldn't have broken. I guess.

Comment: Removing this file for me immediately allowed Docker Desktop to start. Version 4.13.1. Shortcut for explorer:
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Docker`

Comment: Or `%APPDATA%\Docker`. I had to stop the Docker service, then rename/remove the last 3 files in the image above, then start Docker.

Comment: In my case just the _Docker subnet_ or `vpnkitDICR` had to be changed. When I renamed the `settings.json` file Docker had created a new one with a valid subnet.

Comment: yes, throw away or rename `settings.json` helps. Unfortunately this is true for current `Docker version 20.10.20, build 9fdeb9c` too.

There are many more things changed than `vpnkitCIDR`, so I couldn't identify the issue and had to restart with fresh settings from stock.

Comment: huh. worked instantly; as soon as I deleted the file the docker EULA popped up. I should have suspected something when I opened settings.json and np++ just said NULL,NULL etc.

Answer (score 8):

Fix: Manually remove this file \AppData\Roaming\Docker\locked-directories

I additionally run C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe
and closed it gracefully.

After that it worked for me though i haven't tried a reboot.

Edit: Yes, works after a reboot as well

Comment: for me all I actually had to do was kill Docker Desktop.exe which was still running

Answer (score 3):

Try also delete roaming/docker-desktop only inner files.

Comment: Hi @Pablo, I tried that but it didn't help me. I have posted the answer which worked for me. Anyways thanks for the update

Comment: FWIW this fixed the problem for me. I had to delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\Desktop folder (not the "Docker Desktop" folder. Your answer was confusing because you have docker-desktop which didn't exist for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are experiencing this on v 4.13,

Then a simpler fix is described in the Docker for windows [issue: docker desktop failed to initialize](Per https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13025) from Oct 2022.

You don't have to *delete* `%AppData%\Roaming\settings.json`,
just change a value in it.

Look for `"vpnkitCIDR"` in that settings.json file. If its value is:

```json
  "vpnkitCIDR": "192.168.65.0/28",
```

... then the fix is:

1. Kill the Docker Desktop process (if running)
2. in `%AppData%\Roaming\settings.json`, change the value to

```json
  "vpnkitCIDR": "192.168.65.0/24",
```

3. Run Docker Desktop

Answer (score 2):

I just killed the already running docker-desktop from the task manager and started docker desktop again, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to make it work agian by opening task admin and ending the docker task, apparently it was "running" but not really, maybe a bug but oh well just try that maybe you get it working without deleting or reinstalling anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had to:

1. delete "Docker" and "Docker Desktop" folders from C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming
2. log out of Windows

after logging in to Windows, I was presented with a new "Docker Subscription Service Agreement" which I had to accept, then:

3. [Start] the Docker Desktop service (Windows will ask you for elevated access.)
4. login with my Docker account

This got it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting docker folders in AppData\Roaming or AppData\Roaming  did not work. Rolling back from v4.x to 3.6 worked.

Comment: Just to expand on potential solution, I experienced this with version 4.10.1. Attempted all of the above to no avail. No dice on 4.10.0 either... I ended up backing up one release at a time and finally restored functionality with 4.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing following hidden folder
`C:\Users\{...}\.docker`

Answer (score 0):

For MacOs users, I tried everything on this thread but nothing worked. The solution for me was to delete de hidden .docker folder located at the "Home" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Running `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe` command caused this error message for me:

```
creating rootNode subnodes: constructing 'BackendServices' in 'rootNode': doing migrations: migrating features.json: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value
```

Therefore, I needed to delete the `c:\Users\<username>\.docker\features.json` file, which indeed, contained only 0-bytes.

After this, I was able to start the binary.

Answer (score 0):

None of the "delete folder/file X" solutions worked for me. It ended up being much simpler than that: Open Task Manager and kill the running Docker Desktop process. After that, Docker Desktop started up with no problems.